# Add numbers (values) inputs in each p, and when done alert highest number

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

For example, I have two `p` tags and in each of them are two `input`s (these input just take numbers). I want to add the numbers in each tag `p` on input and when that's done, alert the highest number in these two `p` tags.

Example:

> First `p`: first input number(value) is: `1`, second input
>   is: `2`.
>  Second `p`: first input: `3`, second input is: `4`.
>
> Adding the numbers in each tag `p`:
>  First `p`: `3` **&**
>   Second `p`: `7`
>
> I want to alert `7`, because it is highest
>   number,

How do I do this by jQuery?

My try:(this doesn't work)

```
<p>
    <input type="text" value="1"/>
    <input type="text" value="2"/>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="text" value="3"/>
    <input type="text" value="4"/>
</p>


$('button').live('click', function(){    
    var i = 0;
    $('p').each(function(){        
        $('input',this).each(function(){
            i += Number($(this).val());
            //alert(val);
            //if(val > i)  {i = val; }
        })
        var val = Math.max.apply( Math, $(i).map( function(){
            return 0|this.value;
        }).get());
        alert(val);
    });     
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uj4xr/

Comment: .... what?  I have no idea what you just said.  Can someone fix the English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var max=0;
$("p").each(function(){ 
    var i; 
    $("input",this).each(function(){
        i+= Number($(this).val());
    });
    if (i>max) max=i;
})
alert(max);
```

Answer (score 2):

Or without a framework: http://jsfiddle.net/vxCjU/4/

Comment: I don't know and don't use jQuery, but you can mix and match as you please: Just copy the <script> section into your HTML and decorate your button with the onclick.